# Using sp_OACreate to track if a file is ready to use

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a file in FTP server that is used for data upload. The file is sent from outside party (via FTP) everyday.
I have scheduled the following stored procedure to monitor the last modified date of the file. How can I modify it to make sure the file is ready to use? For instance the file size is very large (2gb), the procedure may be run during transfer period and return false result. Thanks

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetFileDateLastModified] (@fullFileName NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @FS               INT,
          @OLEResult        INT,
          @file_exists      INT,
          @DateLastModified DATETIME

  EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist
    @fullFileName,
    @file_exists OUTPUT

  IF @file_exists = 1
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE @OLEResult = sp_OACreate
          'Scripting.FileSystemObject',
          @FS OUT

        IF @OLEResult <> 0
          RETURN NULL

        EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAMethod
          @FS,
          'GetFile',
          @FS out,
          @fullFileName

        IF @OLEResult <> 0
          RETURN NULL

        EXEC @OLEResult = sp_OAGetProperty
          @FS,
          'DateLastModified',
          @DateLastModified OUT

        IF @OLEResult <> 0
          RETURN NULL
    END
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL

  RETURN @DateLastModified
  END  
GO
```

Comment: Don't call `sp_OACreate` without an accompanying `sp_OADestroy`, you'll leak handles and memory. (And yes, this means call it *always*, regardless of when and what you return -- this is one of those case where `GOTO` comes in handy.)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "make sure the file is ready to use". You can't know that, that's the difficulty with an external process writing. You can check if the last modified date is "far enough in the past that I consider the process done". What that time is will have to be established empirically. As an alternative, don't track the modified date at all, but run the processing at a time where, by mutual agreement, the upload will definitely be finished (and put something like `2017_11_28` in the name so you know it's the right file).

Comment: There is a schedule task to transfer the file from outside everyday. We are not able to control that schedule. We need to make sure the file is transferred completed before we are able to upload to system